# Missing characters in ctex

Tags: xetex, ctex

When using `ctex` combined with `xeLatex`, I found there are some missing characters in `ctex`, so I wonder how to solve this issue ?

For example, character `祂`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\begin{document}
你就是祂
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I tried with TeX Live from 2016 to 2019 and always got four characters. Can you please show the log file?

Comment: @egreg Sure. I tried with VScode latexshop and overleaf, but neither of them could work. Here is the Overleaf link, you can find the log file here. https://www.overleaf.com/read/bwjzvcmvnrfm

Comment: You get `There is no 祂 in font [FandolSong-Regular.otf]/OT`. Use a different font; the manuals of `ctex` are in Chinese, so I'm not able to suggest how to do it.

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much ! After I referred to `ctex` manual, now I have worked it out.

Answer (score 2):

According to [ctex Chinese manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/language/chinese/ctex/ctex.pdf)(page 9), changing the font can solve the character missing problem:

```
\documentclass[UTF8,nofonts]{ctexart}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
\setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=STHeiti]{STXihei}
\setCJKmonofont{STFangsong}

\begin{document}
你就是祂
\end{document}
```